# Component not rerendering on redux store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im really struggling through this but I cannot get my component to rerender even though I can see the store is changing and yes Im not sure Im not mutating my original state.

Reducer:

```
const AssessmentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ASSESSMENT_INFO:
      return { ...state, assessment: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Action:

```
import { GET_ASSESSMENT_INFO } from '../reducers/AssessmentReducer'
import API from '../../api'

export function getAssessment(assessment) {
  return {
    type: GET_ASSESSMENT_INFO,
    payload: assessment,
  }
}

export function getAssesmentInfo(id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return API.get_all('assessments/' + id).then(
      (response) => dispatch(getAssessment(response)),
      (error) => console.log('An error occurred', error)
    )
  }
}
```

Component:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const assessmentId = this.props.match.params.assessment_id
    this.props.getAssesmentInfo(assessmentId)
}
/** A whole bunch of stuff in here ***/
render() {
    console.log(this.props.assessment)
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    //screenQuestions: state.ScreenQuestionsReducer.screenQuestions,
    assessment: state.AssessmentReducer.assessment,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAssesmentInfo })(
  withStyles(styles)(AssessmentTabs)
)
```

Im seeing my initial state being logged in the render, Can validate the action is called and dispatched to the reducer with the correct payload. But the console log in the render is never hit again. Using redux dev tools, the state is being updated correctly as well.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

as soon as a click a button in my component and update the state, it reads in the new props from redux no problem

Comment: Do you have shouldComponentUpdate() in your component?

Comment: No I dont, and I dont think I should need it, that defaults to true and should be allowing updating no matter what. ComponentDidUpdate is never called either

Comment: @Kierchon Did your redux use react-thunk or react-saga to deal with asynchronous operation?

Comment: @VoQuocThang yes its using thunks

Comment: @Kierchon Code in your question looks ok but it obviously isn't the whole story so without random guesses it's not possible to answer the question. My advice is to checkout a test branch in your repo and replace the component with a minimal component (dispatch on mount and show redux state). Then add things like WithStyles and such to see when it breaks.

Comment: This was because I was on an old version of redux, a new version of react and and old version of react-dom. Once I upgraded everything it all worked